# Trouble understanding what the X (1.66667 mostly) is for

Tags: javascript, math, svg, geometry

I am trying to figure out what the 1.666666666666667. is from in this function. (The function works for what I need but is a stripped down version of it. Just trying to understand it better, came to that number via brute force method, was wondering if there is a dynamic way of getting it?

Also if anyone can shed light on how I can change the function for the better or rather add in the code I found here: http://xahlee.info/js/svg_circle_arc.html (I have implemented parts) but I do not fully understand any of the rotMatrix data would be very appreciated.

```js
var gaugeSweep = 300;
var currentValue = 15;
var maxValue = 15;
var currentAngle = (currentValue * gaugeSweep) / maxValue;
var value = getArcPath(0, currentAngle, false);

document.getElementById("foo").setAttribute("d", value);

function getArcPath(startingAngle, endingAngle, isStatic) {
    const startingPt = getCoordinatesForAngle(4.7, startingAngle, gaugeSweep);
    const endingPt = getCoordinatesForAngle(4.7, endingAngle, gaugeSweep);

    const X = maxValue / 1.666666666666667;
    const largeArc = isStatic ? 1 : gaugeSweep > 180 ? (currentValue > X ? 1 : 0) : 0;

    return ['M', startingPt.x, startingPt.y, 'A', 4.7, 4.7, 0, largeArc, 1, endingPt.x, endingPt.y].join(' ');
}

function getCoordinatesForAngle(radius, angleInDegrees, gaugeSweep) {
  const angleInRadians = ((angleInDegrees - 90 - gaugeSweep / 2) * Math.PI) / 180.0;
  // const angleInRadians = angleInDegrees * (Math.PI / 180); // <-- this is the proper code for angle in radians math wise.

  const centerX = 6;
  const centerY = 6;
  return {
    x: +centerX + radius * Math.cos(angleInRadians),
    y: +centerY + radius * Math.sin(angleInRadians),
  };
};

function sliderOnChange(data) {
  currentValue = data;
  currentAngle = (currentValue * gaugeSweep) / maxValue;
  value = getArcPath(0, currentAngle, false);
  document.getElementById("val").setAttribute("value", data);
  document.getElementById("foo").setAttribute("d", value);
}
```

```html
<h5>
  Gauge Value:
  <input name="range" id="toggle" type="range" min="0" max="15" value="15" onChange="sliderOnChange(+this.value)" />
  <input id="val" value="15" min="0" max="15" type="number" onChange="sliderOnChange(+this.value)"></input>
</h5>

<div style="width: 288px;height: 300px;"><svg viewBox="0 0 12 12" style="border: 1px solid">
  <path id="foo" d="" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

```
var gaugeSweep = 300;
var currentValue = 15;
var maxValue = 15;
var currentAngle = (currentValue * gaugeSweep) / maxValue;
var value = getArcPath(0, currentAngle, false);

document.getElementById("foo").setAttribute("d", value);

function getArcPath(startingAngle, endingAngle, isStatic) {
    const startingPt = getCoordinatesForAngle(4.7, startingAngle, gaugeSweep);
    const endingPt = getCoordinatesForAngle(4.7, endingAngle, gaugeSweep);

    const X = maxValue / 1.666666666666667;
    const largeArc = isStatic ? 1 : gaugeSweep > 180 ? (currentValue > X ? 1 : 0) : 0;

    return ['M', startingPt.x, startingPt.y, 'A', 4.7, 4.7, 0, largeArc, 1, endingPt.x, endingPt.y].join(' ');
}

function getCoordinatesForAngle(radius, angleInDegrees, gaugeSweep) {
  const angleInRadians = ((angleInDegrees - 90 - gaugeSweep / 2) * Math.PI) / 180.0;
  // const angleInRadians = angleInDegrees * (Math.PI / 180); // <-- this is the proper code for angle in radians math wise.

  const centerX = 6;
  const centerY = 6;
  return {
    x: +centerX + radius * Math.cos(angleInRadians),
    y: +centerY + radius * Math.sin(angleInRadians),
  };
};
```

Comment: that's one and two-thirds

Comment: That’s 5 / 3. Are you asking what the number 5 / 3 is? _“came to that number via brute force method”_ — for what purpose? What is your code supposed to do? What sort of answer do you expect?

Comment: Just letting you know that there is a simpler way of doing this. Instead of recalculating the d attribute of the patth you can use the stroke-dasharray for this. Please read this article: https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/

Comment: Yes stroke-dasharray is easier, especially when using a <circle> tag instead.  However (missing from this code was the requirement to add numbers to a path that are dynamically generated,  I mashed together the code from the url and the code from this url: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44876955/convert-svg-semi-circle-arc-to-full-circle-arc-using-path

Comment: These two mixed together is what I came up with above (with a lot more, but not relevant cause I just trying to understand the 1 and 2/3 was doing besides making the number from 15 to 9 (15 can be dynamic as well) and every time I changed it the sweep required the equation to be divisible by 1.66666... etc. just wonder why that number?

Comment: working version of the above code in angular 8+
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-evvqzf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to me that `X` helps you determine `largeArc`, a Boolean indicating whether or not the arc is "large." By this line:

```
const largeArc = isStatic ? 1 : gaugeSweep > 180 ? (currentValue > X ? 1 : 0) : 0;
```

we know that all static arcs are large. If an arc is not static, it is large if the gauge sweep is over 180 or the current value is greater than a certain multiple of the max value. This multiple is `X`. Currently, a non-static angle with gauge sweep 180 or less is large if the current value is over 15 / 1.6... = 9 times the max value.
More descriptive variable names, especially for `X`, would make the code more readable.

Comment: Agreed and yes, but why 1.6? thats the question (what's magic about the 1.66?)

Comment: It seems arbitrary, as do the rest of the numbers in the code (except the 180 cutoff for `gaugeSweep`).

Comment: Very arbitrary, but I feel that there is a mathematical reason for that number.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-evvqzf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: its on line 165 anyone wondering where in gauge.component.ts 
this is a working angular 8+ version of the above code.